# GraphQL: unexpected variables in variableValues: first when using no variables in args

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, hasura

My GraphQL Query works just fine in Hasura Client but fails to work when I use the query in my React code using Apollo, I don't understand why because I am not even using variables in my query! It's a simple query to return some parameters and that's all.

The error I'm getting: ***Error: GraphQL error: unexpected variables in variableValues: first***

**query**

```
query MyQuery {
  account_ledger {
    transaction_id
    transaction_amount
  }
}
```

**response**

```
{
  "data": {
    "account_ledger": [
      {
        "transaction_id": 10049661150662448,
        "transaction_amount": 16850
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10094930139273068,
        "transaction_amount": 1600
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10061887587054946,
        "transaction_amount": 3760
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10056380885643976,
        "transaction_amount": 2460
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10010518554558650,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10000853716813392,
        "transaction_amount": 17190
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10070427147011012,
        "transaction_amount": 1410
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1240017190513613300,
        "transaction_amount": 16240
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10053817340697928,
        "transaction_amount": 2600
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10034938191128572,
        "transaction_amount": 16440
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660038224661446400,
        "transaction_amount": 130
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10006434778973120,
        "transaction_amount": 2120
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10095565557984748,
        "transaction_amount": 16430
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660004583855052700,
        "transaction_amount": 9320
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10019142513951312,
        "transaction_amount": 17000
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10027966903605936,
        "transaction_amount": 2300
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10011672164287928,
        "transaction_amount": 16250
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 980086033556355200,
        "transaction_amount": 4850
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 980028014087081700,
        "transaction_amount": 5050
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 980055033146164600,
        "transaction_amount": 5150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 980005568496321000,
        "transaction_amount": 5000
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10030827020448600,
        "transaction_amount": 17000
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10063142951225168,
        "transaction_amount": 18900
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10047316425266172,
        "transaction_amount": 16900
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10097336206029004,
        "transaction_amount": 18700
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10068032212373680,
        "transaction_amount": 17000
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10082050265318940,
        "transaction_amount": 19500
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10092276780229294,
        "transaction_amount": 17180
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10006145444961766,
        "transaction_amount": 1620
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660085561999932800,
        "transaction_amount": 17280
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660043628285005400,
        "transaction_amount": 1820
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660044030786432300,
        "transaction_amount": 600
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 761172323,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 7611723231,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 76117232312,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 761172323122,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 7611723231232,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 76117232312320,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 761,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 860,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 862,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 863,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 864,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 865,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 866,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 861,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 867,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 661,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 662,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 663,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 664,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 665,
        "transaction_amount": 1100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 666,
        "transaction_amount": 1200
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660031381225350700,
        "transaction_amount": 17000
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660055622930881700,
        "transaction_amount": 16950
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10067652780504088,
        "transaction_amount": 16850
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10064787647732094,
        "transaction_amount": 18050
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10084582774676448,
        "transaction_amount": 16950
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10017650062766650,
        "transaction_amount": 2300
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10006881632039372,
        "transaction_amount": 17050
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10053397273173264,
        "transaction_amount": 1250
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 930095201762428900,
        "transaction_amount": 1750
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10088957448686158,
        "transaction_amount": 50
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10005735742902668,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10039337345886142,
        "transaction_amount": 50
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10095366516766772,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10002284245705388,
        "transaction_amount": 50
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10017259791814902,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10044872520277520,
        "transaction_amount": 50
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10035665897251460,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10061642617112248,
        "transaction_amount": 40
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10039927385620880,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10083939482614400,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10073607403232724,
        "transaction_amount": 30
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10033371940279358,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10088685020263100,
        "transaction_amount": 20
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 22,
        "transaction_amount": 16000
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 23,
        "transaction_amount": 16000
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 24,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 25,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 26,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 27,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 28,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 29,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10052970351706668,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10011441832995856,
        "transaction_amount": 140
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10074836284836260,
        "transaction_amount": 140
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10060348035311556,
        "transaction_amount": 140
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10023908034579110,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10003729765773552,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10009852337755392,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10010841803656860,
        "transaction_amount": 140
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10082042605144656,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10097882731962284,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10034187763149790,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10019268324692048,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10073354499357328,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10022720971260844,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10036105037082676,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1240012452291359700,
        "transaction_amount": 800
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 65,
        "transaction_amount": 50
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 66,
        "transaction_amount": 50
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 67,
        "transaction_amount": 50
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660074765219966200,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210003769118153700,
        "transaction_amount": 90
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10003251950168978,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10042118465931976,
        "transaction_amount": 10330
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210053252806492200,
        "transaction_amount": 6780
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210018828770363100,
        "transaction_amount": 6780
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210051091991692500,
        "transaction_amount": 7950
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210072103849991200,
        "transaction_amount": 6570
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210086083636617200,
        "transaction_amount": 16900
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210029898681119200,
        "transaction_amount": 17240
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210085007415861000,
        "transaction_amount": 1970
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210049037843518000,
        "transaction_amount": 600
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210098702262983700,
        "transaction_amount": 16860
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210064164940352500,
        "transaction_amount": 2100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210019858403530200,
        "transaction_amount": 8380
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210034988617398500,
        "transaction_amount": 11020
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210051731223911000,
        "transaction_amount": 16790
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210009587405115100,
        "transaction_amount": 10400
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210034874768594200,
        "transaction_amount": 8810
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210075996428822300,
        "transaction_amount": 400
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210025972523952600,
        "transaction_amount": 400
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210074234210654700,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210018864025111600,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220046466945273000,
        "transaction_amount": 8810
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220039368270792000,
        "transaction_amount": 300
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220055686726592800,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1230069608553236700,
        "transaction_amount": 14130
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1230049281258490400,
        "transaction_amount": 700
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1230076765081214200,
        "transaction_amount": 450
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1250016782944385000,
        "transaction_amount": 11530
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1250006322554225700,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 92,
        "transaction_amount": 0
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1260056740683290000,
        "transaction_amount": 14680
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1260000587430961200,
        "transaction_amount": 850
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1270009889953397500,
        "transaction_amount": 10030
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1270069561523095000,
        "transaction_amount": 200
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1270040728281643300,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1280089283063438300,
        "transaction_amount": 12130
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1290018809331110700,
        "transaction_amount": 9580
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1290018531674695000,
        "transaction_amount": 900
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1300092766392609800,
        "transaction_amount": 10690
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1310032366810782200,
        "transaction_amount": 6710
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320039283411532800,
        "transaction_amount": 12930
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320089148138786600,
        "transaction_amount": 7530
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1310055191630637600,
        "transaction_amount": 4820
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1280027283326259000,
        "transaction_amount": 3870
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1270067351481026000,
        "transaction_amount": 3760
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210086571828474600,
        "transaction_amount": 4860
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210085983026421800,
        "transaction_amount": 5410
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10073356779506812,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210038099742391800,
        "transaction_amount": 40
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210058115288376600,
        "transaction_amount": 50
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210057437787905000,
        "transaction_amount": 60
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210015214279570200,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210090907123932200,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210058639382087400,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320035737920998700,
        "transaction_amount": 30
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1310051492659050500,
        "transaction_amount": 50
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1300026927515702500,
        "transaction_amount": 70
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1290091342549902300,
        "transaction_amount": 120
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320036065217106200,
        "transaction_amount": 20
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210049711662146000,
        "transaction_amount": 5690
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220017854791655400,
        "transaction_amount": 700
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220078421115568000,
        "transaction_amount": 1750
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220083395141670100,
        "transaction_amount": 2960
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220030012017524700,
        "transaction_amount": 1200
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220055092313143300,
        "transaction_amount": 2150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320090855530790400,
        "transaction_amount": 1450
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320078099626775600,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1310032467080039000,
        "transaction_amount": 1650
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1300045829832479500,
        "transaction_amount": 560
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1300013466915302400,
        "transaction_amount": 14780
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1300099794055548400,
        "transaction_amount": 3520
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1290072756390477000,
        "transaction_amount": 9320
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1280011366293507800,
        "transaction_amount": 15040
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1270012525410060800,
        "transaction_amount": 10880
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1260070060344229600,
        "transaction_amount": 11880
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1250032130776101600,
        "transaction_amount": 13940
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1240053126654134800,
        "transaction_amount": 15490
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220060884920798200,
        "transaction_amount": 9920
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210080012744477200,
        "transaction_amount": 9740
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210052702048120000,
        "transaction_amount": 4700
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320024252859871500,
        "transaction_amount": 9650
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1310094414527099400,
        "transaction_amount": 6460
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1310056800863432400,
        "transaction_amount": 4070
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1300014658278860800,
        "transaction_amount": 6630
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1270021744715695400,
        "transaction_amount": 6560
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1280078733105218300,
        "transaction_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1290031146040661800,
        "transaction_amount": 800
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1250043243699198700,
        "transaction_amount": 1060
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1260074577088146400,
        "transaction_amount": 1550
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1240079422127403800,
        "transaction_amount": 1210
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1230066909606585900,
        "transaction_amount": 860
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220093146897979600,
        "transaction_amount": 1950
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660054591134494100,
        "transaction_amount": 150
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210042973935054800,
        "transaction_amount": 8530
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1110005056867557900,
        "transaction_amount": 12560
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660065337505725200,
        "transaction_amount": 2830
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210048633076725500,
        "transaction_amount": 10080
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660042962566730400,
        "transaction_amount": 70
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220019457336956200,
        "transaction_amount": 10480
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1230049773618436600,
        "transaction_amount": 8590
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1230005784509563400,
        "transaction_amount": 200
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1240008046475998200,
        "transaction_amount": 9570
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1250099610071777800,
        "transaction_amount": 8470
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1260069686742661600,
        "transaction_amount": 10080
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1270011524033094100,
        "transaction_amount": 7140
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1270019972074937900,
        "transaction_amount": 1650
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1280073924483977200,
        "transaction_amount": 9580
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1290037476572969700,
        "transaction_amount": 8560
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1300082875136748000,
        "transaction_amount": 9800
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1310051688097257000,
        "transaction_amount": 9170
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320098945494239000,
        "transaction_amount": 10050
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320034084409829400,
        "transaction_amount": 8820
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320054553717965600,
        "transaction_amount": 200
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210049795161025000,
        "transaction_amount": 11410
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220012186401975000,
        "transaction_amount": 7160
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220041269729137200,
        "transaction_amount": 7680
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1230003827607650300,
        "transaction_amount": 4240
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1240075832098474000,
        "transaction_amount": 6900
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1250055044105082000,
        "transaction_amount": 4650
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1260079730354037200,
        "transaction_amount": 5870
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1270049938656869000,
        "transaction_amount": 3270
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1280024380770806800,
        "transaction_amount": 4130
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1290068008641940500,
        "transaction_amount": 3840
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1300003731064551000,
        "transaction_amount": 4090
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1310066167877878500,
        "transaction_amount": 4270
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320013107002314000,
        "transaction_amount": 10310
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 980036644687427800,
        "transaction_amount": 80
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210076855150837500,
        "transaction_amount": 3480
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210067195942165000,
        "transaction_amount": 4800
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220061444025905400,
        "transaction_amount": 4160
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220078616596051700,
        "transaction_amount": 3570
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1230067056292351500,
        "transaction_amount": 1970
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1230067494033167400,
        "transaction_amount": 2420
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1240045245048555000,
        "transaction_amount": 2520
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1240072489837079600,
        "transaction_amount": 8390
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1250014234261423400,
        "transaction_amount": 2770
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1290096273215510300,
        "transaction_amount": 810
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1290059061625999000,
        "transaction_amount": 2260
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1300037633594074000,
        "transaction_amount": 3860
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1300097680810671000,
        "transaction_amount": 2750
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1310044781273419000,
        "transaction_amount": 3170
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1310079256318178600,
        "transaction_amount": 3450
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320045676617182000,
        "transaction_amount": 3430
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320028368751801300,
        "transaction_amount": 7570
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1320060246343053000,
        "transaction_amount": 5110
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1250036598503759600,
        "transaction_amount": 12410
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1250069488455480300,
        "transaction_amount": 6920
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1290068027769932800,
        "transaction_amount": 5650
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210060048671908400,
        "transaction_amount": 3380
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210034313810243800,
        "transaction_amount": 1160
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1220020357549118700,
        "transaction_amount": 610
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1230094506505520000,
        "transaction_amount": 3160
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 30,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 31,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 32,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 33,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 34,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 35,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 36,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 37,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660060829304660200,
        "transaction_amount": 80
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10020030573503408,
        "transaction_amount": 7320
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 930040052470111600,
        "transaction_amount": 15680
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 38,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 39,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 40,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 41,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 1210095979140740900,
        "transaction_amount": 500
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 10045419846093900,
        "transaction_amount": 700
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 930096692414933100,
        "transaction_amount": 1210
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660067907945384100,
        "transaction_amount": 6350
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 980016732844407800,
        "transaction_amount": 7410
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 990026098619609200,
        "transaction_amount": 11980
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660055069426220000,
        "transaction_amount": 11880
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 48,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 49,
        "transaction_amount": 10
      },
      {
        "transaction_id": 660016665040405800,
        "transaction_amount": 10460
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

const GET_USERS = gql`
  query {
    account_ledger {
      transaction_id
      transaction_amount
    }
  }
`;
const App = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USERS, {
    variables: { first: 10 },
  });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) {
    console.log("error graphql ", error);
    return <p>{`Error: ${error.message}`}</p>;
  }

  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Hello, World</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import App from "./App";

// Initialize a new cache
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

// Creating the client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql",
  cache,
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: you are using variable in the useQuery that's why you get an error . see the example in appolo [doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usequery). You need two remove the second param from `useQuery` or change your query

Answer (score 2):

You have to do either of the following. these are

**1. You have to remove the variable fields when you request the server.**
as [@antoineso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14522591/antoineso) suggested.

> ```
>   const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USERS, {
>     variables: { first: 10 },
>   });
> ```

change the above code to

> ```
>   const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USERS});
> ```

In this case, you will get all ledger information from the server.

But if you want to limit the amount of data coming to your client, then you have to use Hasura's limit and offset. like this

**2. Change your query definition into something like this.**

> ```
>  const GET_USERS = gql`query ledger_query($limit: Int!, $offset:Int!) {
>      account_ledger(limit: $limit, offset: $offset) {
>        transaction_id
>        transaction_amount
>      }   
>  }`;
> ```

Now, you can call your graphql server (Hasura) like this.

> ```
> const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USERS, {
>   variables: { limit: 10, offset: 0 },
> });
> ```

After doing the above, the server should return the first 10 `account_ledger` information.

Ask me if it is not clear to you.